# How do you dynamically place a control on a canvas in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas

I'm trying to place a control that I have created on my `Canvas`.  The idea is to be able to dynamically add them on the fly.  Like on a button click or at the end of a `DispatchTimer`.  I have the following, but it doesn't work:

```
    FirstCircleControl mc = new FirstCircleControl();
    Canvas.SetLeft(mc, 100);
    Canvas.SetTop(mc, 100);
```

I don't see any control appear...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the control to the `Canvas` first.

```
yourCanvas.Children.Add(mc)
```

Answer (score 6):

Placing a control inside a canvas or grid is a two-step process.

1. Add the control to the container's child collection
2. Set the control's location within the container

You've got the 2nd step, but are missing the first.

**For a canvas**

```
Button childButton = new Button();
LayoutCanvas.Children.Add(childButton);
Canvas.SetLeft(childButton, 120);
Canvas.SetTop(childButton, 120);
```

**For a grid**

```
Button childButton = new Button();
LayoutGrid.Children.Add(childButton);
Grid.SetRow(childButton, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(childButton, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I noticed I also needed to set the width and height of my control to make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

Another (easier in some cases) way for doing it is from the `UIElement` side:

```
    (controlItem as UIElement).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, topVal);
    (controlItem as UIElement).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
```